# Why is this string operation not working?

Tags: c++

Here is the code:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string sidelength;
    cout << "Perimeter of Square" << endl;
    cout << "Enter length of one side: ";
    getline(cin, sidelength);
    cout << sidelength * 4 << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

When run, this is the error message:

> error: no match for 'operator*' (operand types are 'std::__cxx11::string {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}' and 'int')|

How do I fix this error and make the program run correctly?

Comment: How to you multiply a string of characters?

Comment: ***error: no match for 'operator*'*** Says that multiplying a string of characters is not defined.

Comment: I do not know because I am still learning, the string is meant to be inputted as a number but I do not know the number equivalent of a string

Comment: Can't you just input an integer?

Comment: Multiplying "2" * 8 makes as much sense as "boat" * 8.  Numeric types can be multiplied, not strings.

Comment: It does not let me input an integer because the error persists

Comment: `int sidelength; cin >> sidelength; sidelength *= 4; cout << sidelength << endl;`

Comment: You are multiplying numbers, thus the data type needs to be `int`, `long`, `double`, some numeric type.

Answer (score 1):

The get line function takes a string as it's second parameter, but you want to get an integer/double/float as an input. So don't use getline. Simply run this code below and it will solve your problem.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int sidelength;
    cout << "Perimeter of Square" << endl;
    cout << "Enter length of one side: ";
    cin >> sidelength;
    cout << sidelength * 4 << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No need to include cmath by the way.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to multiply a string by a number, you can overload `operator*`:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
#include <string>

std::string operator*(const std::string &s,int x) {
    std::string result;
    try {
        result = std::to_string(stoi(s)*x);
    } catch(const std::invalid_argument&) {
        result="UND";
    }
    return result;
}

std::string operator*(const std::string &s,double x) {
    std::string result;
    try {
        result = std::to_string(stof(s)*x);
    } catch(const std::invalid_argument&) {
        result="UND";
    }
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    std::string input("1");
    input = input * 5.32;
    std::cout << input << std::endl;
    input = input * 2;
    std::cout << input << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```